# How to check 2 conditions in while loop at the same time

Tags: python

## The Question

Write a program that asks the user to enter their name and grades for all the courses they took this
semester. Check that the name is composed of only letters and that each grade entry is composed of
numbers only. When the user has entered all their grades, they may enter -1 to indicate they are done.
Calculate the average grade and display that to the user.

## Sample given to me

```
Enter your name: Sar@
Please enter a valid name.
Enter your name: sara
Enter your grade for course 1: 90
Enter your grade for course 2: 90s
Please enter a valid grade.
Enter your grade for course 2: 80
Enter your grade for course 3: 70
Enter your grade for course 4: 60
Enter your grade for course 5: -1
Sara, your average grade for 4 courses this semester is 75.0. Well done!
```

## My progress

```
count=0
sum=0
name = input("Enter your name: ")
while name.isalpha()==False:
    print("Please enter a valid name.")
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
grade = int(input("Enter your grade for course "+ str(count+1)+": "))
grade == 1    
while grade!=-1:
    grade = str(grade)
    while grade.isnumeric()==False:
        print("Please enter a valid grade.")
        grade = input("Enter your grade for course "+ str(count+1)+": ")
    grade =int(grade)
    count+=1
    sum+=grade
    grade = int(input("Enter your grade for course "+ str(count+1)+": "))
avg = sum/count
if avg>60:
    print(name.capitalize(),", your average grade for",count,"courses this semester is",avg,". Well done!")
else:
    print(name.capitalize(),", your average grade for",count,"courses this semester is",avg,". Please do better.")
```

```
I get an int error. though I know why I get the error but have no other way to solve this problem. Please help!
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback - and fix the formatting errors with your question. I imagine that last line isn't supposed to be a code block.

Comment: Side note: `sum=0` is overwriting the built-in `sum()` function. That's not doing any damage in this simple program, but would be a problem if you wanted to use the `sum()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try` `except`

Like this:

```
count=0
sum=0
name = input("Enter your name: ")
while name.isalpha()==False:
    print("Please enter a valid name.")
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
grade = 1    
while grade!=-1:
    try:
        grade = int(input("Enter your grade for course "+ str(count+1)+": "))
        if grade == -1: break
        count+=1
        sum+=grade
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid grade.")
avg = sum/count
if avg>60:
    print(name.capitalize(),", your average grade for",count,"courses this semester is",avg,". Well done!")
else:
    print(name.capitalize(),", your average grade for",count,"courses this semester is",avg,". Please do better.")
```

Comment: If you think this is the solution to your question, please mark it as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got an int error after entering a non-numeric value as your grade. You convert the grade to an int when you define it without checking if it's a numeric value or not. This will raise an exception, you can avoid it by using `try/except` or first checking if `grade` is numeric.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your `while grade.isnumeric()==False:` is failing when user enters nothing. It passes through an empty string and in line

```
grade = int(input("Enter your grade for course "+ str(count+1)+": "))
```

it tries to evaluate it as int although it can't since its an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

You have several things wrong with this homework assignment.

Here are some suggestions:

1. Append to a list `grades =[]` rather than a running grade that is initialized with a '1'.  You don't want the '1' to be part of your average.
2. Use a try/except clause to validate the user input.
3. Compute the average on the list after you exit the while loop.

Comment: This does not answer the question.